# Embedding Python Widgets into Website using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, scikit-image

I'm trying to create a simple website using the Python web framework Flask, so I can connect the site easily to a database. However another thing which I need to be able to set up is a simple image viewer, where users can pick an image from a list and it will be displayed along with a basic widget or two that can alter the contrast etc.

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/viewer.html
shows exactly what I need however I don't know how to embedded this into Flask or HTML so it shows on the website. The data I have is essentially a set of numpy arrays describing an image.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from skimage import data
from skimage.viewer.viewers import ImageViewer

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    image = data.coins()
    viewer = ImageViewer(image)
    return viewer.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the basic code I have so far, but all this does is open the image on my computer as opposed to on the local website.
I have also tried using the mpld3 module but as my images are arrays it wont display them due to this error:

```
In [58]: mpld3.show(image)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-dd9dd39c2ce3> in <module>()
----> 1 mpld3.show(image)


AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

I'm not overly familiar with any kind of web development but so far I have a good understanding of Flask and Jinja2 templates.

Is there any way to be able to embedded this or any other image viewer which I can attach widgets to?
Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I would recommend not doing this at all.

Comment: I really have to, the point is so that once the site is live, people can look at the images and do some quick data analysis, without having to download the images.

Comment: I mean without downloading the actual file and opening it up in some other software, the files are just too large, but I have some code to compress them in the correct way so too not lose too much information.

Comment: Would using javascript and the html canvas tag be any use?